# fbDidLogin is not called when not on the main view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, uiviewcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I run into a problem where fbDidLogin is not being called when integrating the facebook API in my app. Everything works perfectly when i call the API from the main view controller (meaning, the one that the app delegate calls), but in my case, its under the settings view controller. I literally copy pasted the code from the main view controller (where it worked) to the setting view controller, where it doesnt work.

I did add this method to the app delegate which I understand is the issue for most people, but in my case, i think the problem is elsewhere...any help would be awesome.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
return [[settingsvc facebook] handleOpenURL:url];

}
```

Where in the app delegate header:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) Settings *settingsvc;
```

Comment: Where are implement the Facebook session ? in the app delegate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple things.

-You only need to implement fbDidLogin in one spot in your entire application. You do not implement it on each view controller that uses facebook.

-Assuming you followed the Getting Started steps from Facebook's iOS documentation, your Facebook object lives as a property of your app delegate. And your fbDidLogin method is *only* in your app delegate. This should also be the only spot in your code that declares the Facebook variable. That means that whenever you access facebook from anywhere else in your code, you do something like this:

```
ProjectNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectNameAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[appDelegate.facebook someMethod];
```

-Your handleOpenURL and openURL methods in your app delegate should look exactly like in the sample documentation from Facebook, not like the code you posted.

-Personally I prefer to move the Facebook object out of the app delegate into a singleton helper class, but if you are a beginner then this is probably more advanced than you need.

UPDATED INFORMATION ANSWERING COMMENTS:

-someMethod is whatever Facebook method you are looking to call (post on the wall, authenticate, whatever)

-You should put all FBSessionDelegate methods in your app delegate

-You need to implement FBDialogDelegate on your view controller where you post to Facebook

-Then in your view controller when you want to post to the user's wall do something like this:

```
- (void)postToWall {
    ProjectNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectNameAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if (appDelegate.facebook.isSessionValid) {
       //we're logged in so call the post dialog
       [self doPost:nil];
    } else {
        //we're not logged in so call the login and then do the post when it's done
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doPost:) name:@"FBLoginComplete" object:nil]; 
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
                                 @"offline_access",
                                 @"publish_stream",
                                 nil];
        [appDelegate.facebook authorize:permissions];
        [permissions release];

    }
}

-(void)doPost:(NSNotification *) notification {
    ProjectNameAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProjectNameAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if (appDelegate.facebook.isSessionValid) {
        NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       something, @"app_id",
                                       something, @"link",
                                       something, @"picture",
                                       something, @"name",
                                       something, @"caption",
                                       something, @"description",
                                       nil];
        [appDelegate.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
        [params release];
    } 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];       
}
```

-For the above to work, you need to post the NSNotificationCenter message "FBLoginComplete" whenever a login completes (success or fail).

-Note: I wrote the above code without compiling it or testing it so it may not be perfect (but it usually is :)

-Please note: you CANNOT post to a user's wall directly without the dailog being popped up. The user always has the ability to edit the post before it hits their wall.

Comment: This is a great answer...what should be "someMethod" btw?

Comment: @moshikafya In my opinion ,"someMethod" means the action or information that you need from facebook such as "
-(BOOL)isLogin;
-(void)login;
-(void)logout;
-(void)connectFacebook;
-(void)getUserInfo;
-(void)getFriendList;
-(void)sharedFacebook:(YourStructure)parameter"

Comment: I just want to call fbdidlogin so i could post a message on the user's wall. should i put all the delegate methods (fbdidlogin, etc) in the app delegate too?

Comment: See my edited answer above. Also, please check as accepted if you like the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already implement delegation `FBRequestDelegate` on `yourViewController.h` which is not MainViewController ?

`FBRequestDelegate` contain many useful facebook request handler such as.

```
//Called just before the request is sent to the server.
- (void)requestLoading:(FBRequest *)request;

//Called when the server responds and begins to send back data
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;

//Called when an error prevents the request from completing successfully.
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

/** 
  *Called when a request returns and its response has been parsed into
  *an object.
  *The resulting object may be a dictionary, an array, a string, or a number,
  *depending on thee format of the API response.
  */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;

/** 
  *Called when a request returns a response.
  *The result object is the raw response from the server of type NSData
  */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoadRawResponse:(NSData *)data;
```

Wish It can help you !

Comment: @TommyG May I guess, you missed the appdelegate properties for your setting view. Try put this code to yourSettingViewController.h with properties "AppDelegate *mainDelegate;" and yourSettingViewController.h ViewdidLoad method with "mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];" . If it didn't help you better more. I'm really sorry for my confusing answer.